# Navigableset vs Navigablemap

Tags: java, collections

I am new to JAVA and i am really confused about the difference between the two data structures navigableset and navigablemap in terms of both structure and implementation.
Where should we use each of them?

Comment: This question only makes sense if you know the difference between a `Map` and a `Set`. If you have no clue I suggest reading up on their documentation / javadoc

Comment: see [Difference between Set, List and Map in Java](http://www.java67.com/2013/01/difference-between-set-list-and-map-in-java.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A **NavigableMap** extends the SortedMap interface which represents a sorted map. NavigableMap offers methods for obtaining the elements of the map relative to other ones, in the context of a sorted collection. For instance, it has `ceilingEntry(K obj)` method that returns an entry with the lowest key that is greater or equal to the object passed as an argument. Or the `lastEntry()` method, that returns an entry with the greatest key, and so on.

A **NavigableSet** extends the SortedSet interface and as well as NavigableMap interface provides methods for navigating elements over your set. For example, it has `pollFirst()` method that retrieves and removes the lowest element in the set.

The **difference** between them is that represent the *different data structures*. Although some Set implementations tend to be backed by an appropriate Map implementation, you shouldn't be concerned about implementation details and think of them as two distinct data structures.

The **NavigableMap** represents a Map, that is additionally sorted in terms of a client. The Map is a data structure that associates its elements with certain keys so that these elements could be obtained by that keys.

The **NavigableSet** interface represents a Set that is sorted in terms of a client. A set is an unordered collection of distinct elements (i.e it doesn't store duplicates).

So use the *NavigableSet* when you need an ordered Set and operations it does provide, and the *NavigableMap* when you need an ordered Map and it's functionality. Functionality for both is specified in the corresponding documentation chapters.

Comment: there is no need for a `Set` to be *unordered*, otherwise a `NavigableSet` could not be a `Set` (in Java, mathematics is another case)

Comment: @riguron thanks for such detailed answer

Comment: @Carlos Set is an unordered collection, you get no guarantee on which order element will be stored. 

Though some of the Set implementation e.g. LinkedHashSet maintains order. Also SortedSet and SortedMap e.g. TreeSet and TreeMap maintain a sorting order, imposed by using Comparator or Comparable.
[link] (http://www.java67.com/2013/01/difference-between-set-list-and-map-in-java.html) See this

Comment: @Abiha `Set` **maybe** unordered. I wrote "no need ... to be unordered", or is it? The point is that a `Set` is a collection of distinct elements, but not **necessarily** (always) an unordered one. (again, Java, but not in mathematical sense). [Official documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Set.html): *"A collection that contains no duplicate elements."*

Comment: Please have a look at this question. I know it says according to your post it is sorted but howcome when I perform the following in this sequence, does it read the last entry as the firstEntry?                                                                         NavigableMap.put(238160122691, arrayListValue);
NavigableMap.put(238160122692, arrayListValue);
NavigableMap.put(238160122693, arrayListValue);
NavigableMap.put(238160122694, arrayListValue);
NavigableMap.put(238060122695, arrayListValue);